# ISLIKE function in excel

Tags: excel, vba, custom-functions-excel

I created in VBA the following custom function and I'm using it in excel.

```
Public Function ISLIKE(ByVal sText As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As Boolean 

   If sText Like sPattern Then 

ISLIKE = True 

   Else 

ISLIKE = False 

   End If 

End Function
```

The problem I have now is that I would like to check if a string is in the form of:

1. First character is a number
2. Second character is either a 'b' or a 's'
3. Characters from the third onwards are optional

I can use '#' for the first character and '*' for the third character onwards but how can I specify whether the second character is either a 'b' or a 's'?

Thanks who those will reply.

Gabriele

Answer (score 4):

`Like "#[abc]*"` would match any string starting with a digit followed by any one of the characters inside the square brackets, and then any other [optional] content.

See docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/wildcard-characters-used-in-string-comparisons

Note your function can be simpler as:

```
Public Function ISLIKE(ByVal sText As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As Boolean 
    ISLIKE = sText Like sPattern
End Function
```